# Join 3 rows of 2 tables and COUNT

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join

I want to make a "**join of ther joins of two tables**". Something like this:

```
SELECT users.nombre, users.apellido,users.id, COUNT(pepe.primero) AS Primero, 
   COUNT(pep.segundo) AS Segundo, 
   COUNT(pe.tercero) AS Tercero

FROM users 
LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v AS pepe ON users.id = pepe.primero
LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v AS pep ON users.id = pep.segundo
LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v as pe ON users.id = pe.tercero

WHERE users.categoria < 3 
GROUP BY users.id
```

This example makes that the columns appears as multipling column results.

it is not the same to join the tables with 3 columns of the same
Can you help me?

Table users

```
id | nombre |apellido
------------------
1|  Julio   |Dutra
2|  Nelson  |infante
3|  Pedro   |Polo
4|  Daniel  |Muñoz
```

Table ligauruguaya_v

```
id| primero|segundo|tercero
 1| 1      |2      |3
 1| 1      |3      |2
 1| 1      |4      |2
```

Results

```
 nombre   |Apellido | Primero | Segudno | Tercero
 Julio    |Dutra    | 3       | 0       | 0
 Nelson   |infante  | 0       | 1       | 2
 Pedro    |Polo     | 0       | 1       | 0
 Daniel   |Muñoz    | 0       | 1       | 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Pedro is aslo Tercero isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way of getting the same result:

```
SELECT u.nombre, u.apellido,u.id, 
    (select count(1) from ligauruguaya_v  where primero=u.id) AS Primero,
    (select count(1) from ligauruguaya_v  where segundo=u.id) AS Segundo,
    (select count(1) from ligauruguaya_v  where Tercero=u.id) AS Tercero
FROM users u 

Result:
nombre  apellido    id  Primero Segundo Tercero
Julio   Dutra       1   3       0       0
Nelson  Infante     2   0       1       2
Pedro   Polo        3   0       1       1
Daniel  Muñoz       4   0       1       0
```